# Python: Exceptions were not forwared to a file once launched as Windows Service. Why?

Tags: python, windows-services

I forward std out and error to files. In normal execution mode this results in my prints were printed to out.txt and once an exception occours, it is printed to err.txt.

```
sys.stdout = open(os.path.join(logDirectory, "out.txt"), "w")
sys.stderr = open(os.path.join(logDirectory, "err.txt"), "w")
```

But if I run the program as a Windows Service in debug mode, things change:

```
print("Hi") -> printed to out.txt
sys.stderr.write("error writing") -> printed to err.txt
```

But if I raise an exception:

```
raise Exception("Test")
```

It is not printed to err.txt. Instead it is printed to console:

```
Debugging service MyServiveName - press Ctrl+C to stop.
Error 0xC0000003 - The instance's SvcRun() method failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
```

Why?
Of course it is especially important to get the exceptions in a file if I run the program as a service.

Answer (score 0):

The proble is that the python windows service does its own exception handeling.
The solution is to catch the exception bevore it reaches the service and do your own exception printing.

```
# core logic of the service
def SvcDoRun(self):
    try:
        self.server = MyLauncher()
        self.server.run()
    except:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```